# Web.py Template Not Found

Tags: python, templates, python-2.7, web.py

I followed [this Tutorial](http://webpy.org/cookbook/userauthpgsql) to test my MySQL for Web.py Setup.

As the tutorial has no complete source code I post mine here:

```
import web
import MySQLdb

web.config.debug = False

urls = (
  '/login', 'Login',
  '/reset', 'Reset',
)
app = web.application(urls, locals())
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='dbname', user='user', pw='password')

store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store,
                              initializer={'login': 0, 'privilege': 0})

def logged():
        if session.login==1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
def create_render(privilege):
    if logged():
        if privilege == 0:
            render = web.template.render('/Users/me/Desktop/cpage/Templates/reader')
        elif privilege == 1:
            render = web.template.render('/Users/me/Desktop/cpage/Templates/user')
        elif privilege == 2:
            render = web.template.render('/Users/me/Desktop/cpage/Templates/admin')
        else:
            render = web.template.render('/Users/me/Desktop/cpage/Templates/communs')
    else:
        render = web.template.render('/Users/me/Desktop/cpage/Templates/login')
    return render
class Login:
    def GET(self):
        if logged():
            render = create_render(session.privilege)
            return '%s' % render.login_double()
        else:
            render = create_render(session.privilege)
            return '%s' % render.login()
    def POST(self):
        name, passwd = web.input().name, web.input().passwd
        ident = db.select('example_users', where='name=$name', vars=locals())[0]
        try:
            if hashlib.sha1("sAlT754-"+passwd).hexdigest() == ident['pass']:
                session.login = 1
                session.privilege = ident['privilege']
                render = create_render(session.privilege)
                return render.login_ok()
            else:
                session.login = 0
                session.privilege = 0
                render = create_render(session.privilege)
                return render.login_error()
        except:
            session.login = 0
            session.privilege = 0
            render = create_render(session.privilege)
            return render.login_error()
class Reset:
    def GET(self):
        session.login = 0
        session.kill()
        render = create_render(session.privilege)
        return render.logout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The directory cpage on the Desktop contains as follows:

> DBTest.py Templates  login.html   sessions

In the Templates there is another login.html, just to be sure it is there because the Problem I face is: Server is able to start from the terminal (I'm Running MacOSX Mavericks)
But whenever I enter localhost:port/login it crashes:

```
http://0.0.0.0:1234/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "cpage/DBTest.py", line 48, in GET
    return '%s' % render.login()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/template.py", line 1017, in __getattr__
    t = self._template(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/template.py", line 1011, in _template
    self._cache[name] = self._load_template(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web/template.py", line 1001, in _load_template
    raise AttributeError, "No template named " + name
AttributeError: No template named login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out by myself, probably the best way to learn stuff. 
Either way I wanted to provide the world with the answer.

First of all the Code from the Tutorial had to look a bit different, so this [post helped me a lot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120539/web-py-user-authentication-with-postgresql-database-example?rq=1)

After taking using this code (or better: merging it) I had the same problem.

I finally had to re-organize my folder structure. Adding a layout.html to the Templates folder fixed the problem. Also it is important to use the right path to the directory.